# How do I increase number S, N times, until it reaches number F?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a known `startValue`, a known `finalValue` and a fixed number of allowed `iterations`.

Starting with `startValue` I need to keep increasing the value each time round the loop until I reach `finalValue`.

I want the increase to be **proportional** (gradual).

I'm trying the below and the numbers seem to make sense except for the jump at the start and end of the array.

There seems to be a big jump from the 1st value to the 2nd and another big jump from the one before last to the last one.

The values in between seem to be increasing gradually though.

Is this the correct or best approach?

```js
let startValue = 0.07
let finalValue = 4.76
let iterations = 10

let values = [startValue]

iterations--

while (iterations) {
  let [previousValue] = values.slice(-1)
  let nextValue = (finalValue - previousValue) / iterations
  values.push(nextValue)
  iterations--
}

values.push(finalValue)

document.getElementById('values').innerHTML = `[<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;${values.join(',<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;')}<br>]`
```

```html
<div id="values"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate an array based on the following logic:

1st item: `startValue`

2nd item: `startValue + diff`

3rd item: `startValue + (diff * 2)`

and so on...

```js
const 
  startValue = 0.07,
  finalValue = 4.76,
  iterations = 10,
  diff = (finalValue - startValue) / (iterations - 1),
  values = Array.from({ length: iterations }, (_, i) => startValue + i * diff);

console.log(values);
```

Comment: I realised that your solution performs 11 iterations instead of the requested 10. I'm trying to figure out how it can fixed..

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it should be `diff = (finalValue - startValue) / (iterations-1)` instead.

Comment: @SproutCoder Yes and you also need to update the `length` of the array. I've updated my answer you can refer that.